# Renaming multiple directories adding string after pattern

Tags: command-line, rename

I have some directories that begin with the date. I want to include a string `(name)` after that date. How can I do it?
 - `rename 's/.*-..-../(name) /' *` replaces the date but I don't want to replace it, just to add '(name) '.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&(name)`:

```
rename 's/.*-..-../&(name) /' *
```

`&` refers to the entire text matched by the expression, so instead of replacing it with just `(name)`, you're replacing it with itself and `(name)`.